# custom "register" button on a form - problem with redirection

Tags: 7, redirection, forms

How to make a custom register button in the user login form (block) so that it redirects to 'user/register' ?

Currently, when I click my custom "Register" button, the code in _mymodule_register is executed (I debugged), but the page just reloads, it does not go to user/register. I tried both drupal_goto and form redirect, but nothing works.

```
function mymodule_form_user_login_block_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['actions']['register'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Register'),
    '#submit' => array('_mymodule_register'),
    '#limit_validation_errors' => array(),
  );
}

function _mymodule_register($form, $form_state) {
  $form_state['redirect'] = 'user/register';
  //drupal_goto('user/register');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below code to achieve the same functionality.

```
function mymodule_form_user_login_block_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['actions']['register'] = array(
    '#markup' => l('Register', 'user/register'),
  );
}
```

Theme it using css to look like a button. Done !

Comment: Thanks, that's a good tip! In order to achieve exactly the same look between the true "Login" button and the "Register" link, I had to style also the standard "Login" button (with exactly the same class as "Register" link). This required adding the class to the input submit form element, by adding this line of code at the bottom of the above function: `$form['actions']['submit']['#attributes']['class'][] = 'mybutton';` - now the button and the link look the same